# Sequence of animations in WPF with BeginAnimation

Tags: c#, wpf, animation, graphics

I'm trying to animate some rotations in 3D with WPF and if I trigger them manually (on click) everything is fine, but if I compute the movements that should be made on the Viewport3D all animations seem to go off at the same time.

The code that computes the movements is as follows:

```
for(int i=0; i<40; i++){
    foo(i);
}
```

Where the `foo(int i)` looks like:

```
//compute axis, angle
AxisAngleRotation3D rotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(axis, angle);
RotateTransform3D transform = new RotateTransform3D(rotation, new Point3D(0, 0, 0));
DoubleAnimation animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, angle, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(370)); 

rotation.BeginAnimation(AxisAngleRotation3D.AngleProperty, animation);
```

The computation of `axis` and `angle` is not something time consuming, simple attributions, so I guess the problem is that all animations trigger the next frame since the computations are already done when the current frame is "over".

How can I display those animations sequentially, rather than all at once, in code (not XAML)?

PS: everything is in C#, no XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add multiple animations to a [Storyboard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms634711.aspx) and set each animation's [BeginTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.begintime.aspx) to the sum of the durations of the previous animations:

```
var storyboard = new Storyboard();
var totalDuration = TimeSpan.Zero;

for (...)
{
    var rotation = new AxisAngleRotation3D(axis, angle);
    var transform = new RotateTransform3D(rotation, new Point3D(0, 0, 0));
    var duration = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(370);
    var animation = new DoubleAnimation(0, angle, duration);

    animation.BeginTime = totalDuration;
    totalDuration += duration;

    Storyboard.SetTarget(animation, rotation);
    Storyboard.SetTargetProperty(animation, new PropertyPath(AxisAngleRotation3D.AngleProperty));

    storyboard.Children.Add(animation);
}

storyboard.Begin();
```

Note that i haven't tested the code above, so sorry for any faults.

---

Or you create your animations in a way that each animation (starting from the second one) is started in a [Completed](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.completed.aspx) handler of the previous one.

Comment: I got to say it's a bit better, but still the animations happen in chunks, I mean some trigger simultaneously, some trigger OK.

Comment: Then what about starting each in a Completed handler of the previous?